# How to split or cut the string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.path

I am trying to split the string with python code with following output:

```
import os

f = "Retirement-User-Portfolio-DEV-2020-7-29.xml"

to_output = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
print(to_output)
```

I have received an output :

```
Retirement-User-Portfolio-DEV-2020-7-29
```

However, I want the output like this below and remove "-DEV-2020-7-29" FROM THE STRING:

```
Retirement-User-Portfolio
```

Comment: There are many ways to slice and search strings; these are available in any tutorial on the subject.  What, *specifically* determines where you cut the string?  Why can't you simply lop off the extra chars with a string slice?

Comment: Regex to the rescue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split()` and `join()` to split on the `kth` occurrence of a character.

```
f = "Retirement-User-Portfolio-DEV-2020-7-29.xml"

to_output = '-'.join(f.split('-')[0:3])
```

You should explain your question more with details on the pattern you are trying to match - is it always the third character? Other solutions (e.g., regex) may be more appropriate.

Comment: This seems quite feasible solution. and resolved my issue. It worked! Thanks you !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
f = "Retirement-User-Portfolio-DEV-2020-7-29.xml"
a = f.split('-')

print('-'.join(a[:3]))
```